# Duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SBJsonParser

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I just included AWSIOSSDK.framework and Facebook SDK together in my project, then got a build error:

> ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SBJsonParser in /Users/tom8/Desktop/site1/site1/facebook-ios-sdk/libfacebook_ios_sdk.a(SBJsonParser.o) and /Users/tom8/Desktop/AWSiOSSDK.framework/AWSiOSSDK(SBJsonParser.o) for architecture i386

I use iOS Facebook SDK Static Library, so i could not simply delete sbjson files in facebooksdk folder. I also tried to delete sbjson files in AWSIOSSDK folder, but it also did not work. Could someone give me some advice?

Comment: It is getting SBJsonParser file twice in the project. You need to delete one of the file reference. Either from AWSIOSSDK or from Facebook.

Comment: I know this, but the question is how to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Almost without exception, when I get duplicate symbol build errors, it's because I was #include-ing .h files too prolifically from other .h files. The solution is almost always these two simple steps:

1. move as many #include directives into .m files as possible
2. use @protocol and @class forward-declarations in .h files.

The *only* cases where you *need* to #include an .h from an .h is when you actually extend a class or implement a protocol. If you just need to use a class name or protocol name in a signature, use forward declarations and move the #include to the .m file.

**Example:**

foo.h

```
#include "Bar.h"
#include "BazProtocol.h"
#include "BarDelegateProtocol.h"
@interface Foo:NSObject <BarDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<Baz> myBaz;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Bar *myBar;
@end
```

becomes

```
#include "BarDelegateProtocol.h"
@class Bar;
@protocol Baz;

@interface Foo:NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<Baz> myBaz;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Bar *myBar;
@end
```

Comment: What you describe is certainly a good idea, but it's not going to help with duplicate symbols *linker* errors. You also should use `#import` instead of `#include` to guard against including the same header multiple times into the same compilation unit which will generate duplicated symbol *compiler* errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too. You can delete the files from the Facebook Project itself, but you cannot delete from the framework.

So click:

facebook-ios-sdk.xcodeproj (to open up file contents) -> FBConnect (to view folder contents) -> JSON (to view folder contents) -> remove SBJsonWriter and SBJsonParser.

Try compiling. You should be good to go!

Eva